SQL Oracle How to Create a new row for every date from date range(Status Start - Status End) column
I have a table that shows the status of a device (in service vs out of service) and the date range the device was in that status.



EQUIP ID
STATUS
STATUS START
STATUS END




01
OUT_SVC
07/16/2020
07/21/2020


01
IN_SVC
07/21/2020
07/25/2020



Is there a way to list it so that each status has a line for individual dates in between? EDIT: Without creating a Calander table as this table dates back 2020 to present.
Output expected to look like this:



EQUIP ID
STATUS
STATUS DATE




01
OUT_SVC
07/16/2020


01
OUT_SVC
07/17/2020


01
OUT_SVC
07/18/2020


01
OUT_SVC
07/19/2020


01
OUT_SVC
07/20/2020


01
IN_SVC
07/21/2020


01
IN_SVC
07/22/2020


01
IN_SVC
07/23/2020


01
IN_SVC
07/24/2020


01
IN_SVC
07/25/2020




Look into using a calendar table.

You can use a LATERAL join to a row-generator:
SELECT t.equip_id,
       t.status,
       d.status_date
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT t.status_start + LEVEL - 1 AS status_date
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY t.status_start + LEVEL - 1 <= t.status_end
       ) d

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (EQUIP_ID, STATUS, STATUS_START, STATUS_END) AS
SELECT '01', 'OUT_SVC', DATE '2020-07-16', DATE '2020-07-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01', 'IN_SVC',  DATE '2020-07-21', DATE '2020-07-25' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



EQUIP_ID
STATUS
STATUS_DATE




01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-16 00:00:00


01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-17 00:00:00


01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-18 00:00:00


01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-19 00:00:00


01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-20 00:00:00


01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-21 00:00:00


01
IN_SVC
2020-07-21 00:00:00


01
IN_SVC
2020-07-22 00:00:00


01
IN_SVC
2020-07-23 00:00:00


01
IN_SVC
2020-07-24 00:00:00


01
IN_SVC
2020-07-25 00:00:00




If you don't want the final value in the earlier ranges then:
SELECT t.equip_id,
       t.status,
       d.status_date
FROM   ( SELECT equip_id,
                status,
                status_start,
                status_end,
                LEAD(status_end)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY equip_id ORDER BY status_end) AS next_end
         FROM   table_name
       ) t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT t.status_start + LEVEL - 1 AS status_date
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY t.status_start + LEVEL - 1 < t.status_end
         OR         (   t.next_end IS NULL
                    AND t.status_start + LEVEL - 1 = t.status_end )
       ) d

Which outputs:



EQUIP_ID
STATUS
STATUS_DATE




01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-16 00:00:00


01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-17 00:00:00


01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-18 00:00:00


01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-19 00:00:00


01
OUT_SVC
2020-07-20 00:00:00


01
IN_SVC
2020-07-21 00:00:00


01
IN_SVC
2020-07-22 00:00:00


01
IN_SVC
2020-07-23 00:00:00


01
IN_SVC
2020-07-24 00:00:00


01
IN_SVC
2020-07-25 00:00:00



fiddle

We can make use of a calendar table, one having all expected/required dates, and join with that:
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT date '2020-07-16' AS dt FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2020-07-17' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2020-07-18' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2020-07-19' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2020-07-20' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2020-07-21' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2020-07-22' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2020-07-23' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2020-07-24' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2020-07-25' FROM dual
)

SELECT
    t.EQUIP_ID,
    t.STATUS,
    d.dt AS STATUS_DATE
FROM yourTable t
INNER JOIN dates d
    ON d.dt BETWEEN t.STATUS_START AND t.STATUS_END
ORDER BY
    t.EQUIP_ID,
    d.dt;


We can take data between any dates without specifying each date. SELECT date '2020-07-16' AS dt     FROM dual     UNION ALL     SELECT dt+ INTERVAL '1' DAY     FROM dates     WHERE dt< date '2020-07-25'

@AbdulAlimShakir I have no idea what point you are trying to make, but if you're commenting on my choice for date generation, then I agree there are better ways (e.g. date generation function).  I did it this way just for demo purposes.

We can do following steps to do what you want:
First, we create a table with all the dates from the first date of your status table to the last one using Oracle's CONNECT BY functionality. Thus, we avoid to manually write down a very long list of dates in case your status table has lots of rows.
DECLARE
  v_first_date DATE;
  v_last_date DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    MIN(LEAST(status_start, status_end)),
    MAX(GREATEST(status_start, status_end)) INTO v_first_date, v_last_date
  FROM device_status;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'CREATE TABLE DATES AS 
      SELECT 
        DATE '''  || TO_CHAR(v_first_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') ||
        ''' + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
        CONNECT BY level <= (
        DATE ''' || TO_CHAR(v_last_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''' - 
        DATE ''' || TO_CHAR(v_first_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''' + 1)';
END;
/

Check if the table contains the correct dates: SELECT * FROM dates ORDER BY dt;
Now we join this table and the status table.
First I thought you want simply the following query:
SELECT
  ds.equip_id,
  ds.status,
  d.dt AS status_date
FROM device_status ds
INNER JOIN dates d
  ON d.dt BETWEEN ds.status_start AND ds.status_end
ORDER BY
  ds.equip_id,
  d.dt;

This will return two rows for the same date in case the date appears in both columns status_start end status_end in the status table.
I don't know if this is intended.
Your sample result only shows the row with date = status_start in this case.
If this is the desired logic, then add a GROUP BY clause and fetch the minimum status because I comes before O.
This will produce exactly the result you have shown in your question:
SELECT
  ds.equip_id,
  MIN(ds.status) AS status,
  d.dt AS status_date
FROM device_status ds
INNER JOIN dates d
  ON d.dt BETWEEN ds.status_start AND ds.status_end
GROUP BY
  ds.equip_id,
  d.dt
ORDER BY
  ds.equip_id,
  d.dt;

Verify it's working correctly on this sample fiddle with the data from your question.
Notes:

If you're on older versions of Oracle, you have to add a FROM dual to all queries without FROM.
You write you don't want a calendar table. I don't get this point because a calendar table is the correct way to solve such requirements. If you want to avoid that, you should explain why. In this case, you could use a CTE and join on it.
Above solution expects there are no gaps or missing dates from the first date of the status table to the last one. If this assumption is incorrect, you might need to extend this and/or to explain what to do in this case.


One of the options to do it is using a recursive cte that will create a virtual dynamic calendar for period of dates between Min(STATUS_START) and Max(STATUS_END) dates:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table tbl ( EQUIP_ID VarChar2(6), STATUS VarChar2(12),  STATUS_START Date, STATUS_END Date );

Insert Into tbl (EQUIP_ID, STATUS, STATUS_START, STATUS_END ) 
Select '01', 'OUT_SVC',  To_Date('07/16/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), To_Date('07/21/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy')  From Dual Union All
Select '01', 'IN_SVC',   To_Date('07/21/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), To_Date('07/25/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy')  From Dual;

WITH    --  R e c u r s i v e    C T E : 
  grid ( EQUIP_ID, STATUS, STATUS_START, STATUS_END, STATUS_DATE ) AS
    ( Select    EQUIP_ID, STATUS, 
                Min(STATUS_START) as STATUS_START, 
                Max(STATUS_END) as STATUS_END, 
                Min(STATUS_START) as STATUS_DATE
      From      tbl
      Group By  EQUIP_ID, STATUS 
     UNION ALL
      Select    EQUIP_ID, STATUS, STATUS_START, STATUS_END, 
                STATUS_DATE + 1
      From      grid
      Where     STATUS_DATE >= STATUS_START And STATUS_DATE < STATUS_END
    )

... use Distinct and Case expresssion with Count() Over() analytic function to handle repeating dates (dates having both statuses)
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
Select   Distinct 
         EQUIP_ID, 
         Case When Count(STATUS_DATE) Over(Partition By EQUIP_ID, STATUS_DATE) > 1
              Then 'IN_SVC'
         Else STATUS
         End  as STATUS, 
         STATUS_DATE
From     grid
Order By STATUS_DATE

/*      R e s u l t : 
EQUIP_ID    STATUS     STATUS_DATE
----------  ---------  ----------
01          OUT_SVC    16-JUL-20
01          OUT_SVC    17-JUL-20
01          OUT_SVC    18-JUL-20
01          OUT_SVC    19-JUL-20
01          OUT_SVC    20-JUL-20
01          IN_SVC     21-JUL-20
01          IN_SVC     22-JUL-20
01          IN_SVC     23-JUL-20
01          IN_SVC     24-JUL-20
01          IN_SVC     25-JUL-20      */

See the fiddle here.
